# Weird paging but in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have am building a single page app in React with data loaded from an API. I have next and previous buttons to load new pages of content from the API. This works, but with a strange bug: The first time you click in one direction (next/prev), the API request uses the same page param as before. It's only until the next click in that direction that the update happens.

For example, if I were on page 1, and clicked next, the API call would be for page 1. If I clicked next again, the request would be for page 2. I can keep clicking next after that and get the expected result. However, if I am on say, page 3, and I click previous, the request will be for page 4. Then the following previous click would be for page 3, and then 2, and so on.

In short, it takes one extra click to "start going" in a direction in the pager.

Here's my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getData() {
  fetch(`https://api.example.com/my/api/path?page=${ this.state.page }`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((json) => {
    let data = Object.keys(json.data).map(key => json.data[key]);
    this.setState( { data: data } );
  })
  .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err) });
}

let Item = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { page: 1 };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    getData.call(this);
  },

  handlePageClick(page) {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + page });
    getData.call(this);
  },

  render() {
    let items = this.state.data.map((item) => {

      return (
        <article style={ background() } className={ itemClass }>
          <h1 className="title">{item.name}</h1>
          <div className="description">
            {item.description}
          </div>
        </article>
      )
    });

    return (
      <div className="video-list">
        {items}

        <ul className="paging">
          <li onClick={ this.handlePageClick.bind(this, -1) }>Previous</li>
          <li onClick={ this.handlePageClick.bind(this, 1) }>Next</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` calls are batched in event handlers, so calling it just queues up a state change. As such, the component's state won't have been updated yet when you call `getData`.

[`setState` takes a second argument](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate), which is a callback to be called after state has been updated and the component has re-rendered, so you could do this instead:

```
this.setState({ page: this.state.page + page }, () => getData.call(this));
```

---

I would suggest keeping your data fetching entirely independent of the component if you're not going to make it a method:

```
function getData(page, cb) {
  fetch(`https://api.example.com/my/api/path?page=${ page }`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((json) => {
    let data = Object.keys(json.data).map(key => json.data[key]);
    cb(data)
  })
  .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err) });
}
```

...

```
handlePageClick(change) {
  var page = this.state.page + change
  this.setState({page})
  getData(page, data => this.setState({data}))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using this.state.page in render you would be better off just using a variable with local scope. That will avoid syncing issues.